# How to add Variable and execute to GET Method URL for SMS Gateway

Tags: php, url, laravel-5

I would like to ask about how to execute and add variable for my SMS gateway, in their API, they want to have us execute their GET method URL with some dynamic variable..

for example I have variables:

```
$a = 081111111;
$b = message;
```

and the url should be

```
https://www.examplegatewaysmsprovider.com/url.php?phone=$a&message=$b
```

how should I done these things in the same time

1. Execute the URL so the message can be sent automatically
2. Add the variable to the URL (what I know is to add . in between the url)
3. (Additional) I want to execute it on controller in laravel 5.2

thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can use curl to execute external get request.**

```
$message=urlencode($b);
$url=https://www.examplegatewaysmsprovider.com/url.php?phone=$a&message=$message;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Different Way.**

***step 1.*** we cant set up transaction table which store all SMS text with contact number also having one flag which maintain sms send or not.

***step 2.*** and in next step we can create schedule(cron job) which execute few records from this table and update flag so sms not send twice.

this the better option which i have.

thanks.

Comment: OK, I will give it a try then

Comment: Hi, thanks for awesome answer, but doing this curl is making the execution is little bit slower, do you know what syntax to make this faster? As I said, I am making SMS Gateway which that means I want to execute it faster after the user click a button...

Comment: hi @YukoPangestu please review edits. hope it will helps you.